# JAX-WS with JAXB tutorial

Tags: wsdl, jaxb, jax-ws

I'm getting started in developing web services using JAX-WS. I'm trying to implement classes I can send between my service and client using JAXB, but having trouble getting it to work.

I've tried following the example at [this site](http://www.soastation.org/2007/05/jax-ws-jaxb-rock-and-roll.html) but cannot seem to get it to work. After following the instructions, the test page that's displayed doesn't have any way of defining the Die objects as is suggested by the article.

All of this is very new to me, so I'm really not sure where to go. I've checked the WSDL file linked from the test page, and my best guess is that the JAXB is not working properly as I don't see the Die class or its properties mentioned anywhere.

A good, fully worked example would be very beneficial. Does anyone know where one can be found? If it's any help, I'm working in Netbeans.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a step by step how to for jax-ws.
http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/jax-ws.html

If you google netbeans web services you will find many examples.

Comment: Problem is, these all deal with simple web services with primitive values as parameters and return types. I'm looking to have objects as parameters and return types, which is (to my understanding) where JAXB fits in. The page you linked was the first tutorial I tried, but unfortunately it is again only concerned with primitives as parameters and returns.

Comment: @Mac - Try this one and look at the bottom for the Resources http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jws8.html it will be less netbeans centric but it might help. There is a lot of info at this site here is a search for JAXB http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/search/searchResults.jsp?searchType=1&searchSite=dW&searchScope=dW&query=jaxb&Search=Search

Answer (score 4):

Here is an excellent JAX-WS tutorial for beginners. http://java.globinch.com/enterprise-java/web-services/jax-ws/java-jax-ws-tutorial-develop-web-services-clients-consumers/
The tutorial explains how to develop web service and consumer without using a Java EE container.

Comment: Nice link, but the problem is that almost always, developers want to (or have to) use a JEE container, or at least a servlet container. The tutorial makes one feel JAX-WS is a breeze, until somebody asks you to deploy it on WebSphere, or JBoss, or even Tomcat for that matter.